# Postgres error from within function. How do I debug?

Tags: postgresql, debugging

I am receiving this postgres error from a java app and I would like to be able to debug it more.

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "jiveactfirehose_pk"
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO jiveActivityFirehose (activityIDHi, activityIDLo, activitySystemID, activityContextID, activityContextType, activityDescriptorID, activityDescriptorType, activityParentID, activityParentType, activityTime, activityType, activityUserID, activityLocaleCode, activityProperties, activityAddProperties) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15)
```

I added a line-break to the statement so you can view the values easier.

How do I view the values the parameters without modifying the java code? Is there are way to output the actual values from postgres to the error log?

Comment: Are you able to modify the function? If so you can raise a message (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).  Also, are you not getting an error detail message, like "Key (id)=(...) already exists." (which would indicate the conflicting PK without having to modify the function)?

Comment: There's always the pl/pgsql debugger